# Getting int from char array

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem getting an integer from a char[]. I's a really simple line of code, but I can't see where the problem is.
This is the code:

```
char* rawd = .....
int resultSize = ((int*)rawd)[0];

cout << "BYTES ::: " << (int)(rawd[0]) << " " << (int)(rawd[1]) << " " << (int)(rawd[2]) << " " << (int)(rawd[3]) << endl;
cout << "SIZE RETURNED :::::: " << resultSize << endl;
```

This is what is printed:

```
BYTES ::: 0 0 4 0
SIZE RETURNED :::::: 262144
```

And I'm expecting `resultSize` to be 1024.

Why does `resultSize` contain 262144 intead of 1024?

Comment: Looks like you are expecting big-endian behavior on a little-endian system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd get the conversion you expect on a machine with a "big-endian" processor, like a 68000-series. On   Intel processors -- "little-endian" machines -- the byte order is reversed, and the answer you got is the expected one.

Converting raw memory bytes into into data types like `int`, `double`, etc, is tricky, and if the data potentially comes from another machine, *very* tricky. There are semi-standard functions called `ntohs()`, `ntohl()`, `htons()`, and `htonl()` which convert between host-specific order and standard "network order", which is big-endian; these functions are available on all UNIX-like systems and in some Windows C libraries, as well.

Comment: Wow! The data is comming from the same mahine but from a java vm. I didn't know that jvm was big endian. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, it is. Java is always big endian, even on Intel hardware. That means it always communicates in "network byte order", which is a good feature for a network-facing language.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your system is big-endian, which means that least significant bytes of larger integers are at greater addresses and most significant bytes are at lower.

Little-endian result would be 0 + 4*256 + 0*256<sup>2</sup> + 0*256<sup>3</sup> = 1024

Big-endian result would be 0 + 0*256 + 4*256<sup>2</sup> + 0*256<sup>3</sup> = 262144